# Datetime not binding properly to view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 asp.net project, i am binding datetime from database to the view using ajax,

Here is the ajax code,

```
      $.get(
        '/Child/GetFamilyMemberView', { familyid: hv },
        function (data) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                 
                html += "<p>" + data[i].Family_Member_DateofBirth + "</p>";                 
            }
            $("#getfamilymember").append(html); 
       });
```

After binding the datetime value to view, i get output as,

```
/Date(1104517800000)/
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is happening because your ajax is passing the data in JSON.

Use a function like this one to convert Json date to Javascript Date:

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

    if (parts[2] == undefined) 
      parts[2] = 0;

    if (parts[3] == undefined) 
      parts[3] = 0;

    return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
};
```

Update: use this http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/ to format the javascript Date to string.

If you want to pass the date to string (mm/dd/yyyy):

```
function formatDate(jsDate)
{
   return jsDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + jsDate.getDate() + "/" + jsDate.getYear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks...it works.. Now my output look like "Thu Dec 31 1987 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"...it isnt convenient for the user .. how can i make it "mm/dd/yyyy" format?

Comment: I got corret year by using "jsDate.getFullYear()" instead of "jsDate.getYear()"